# prevent touchstart when swiping with touchswipe

Tags: jquery, swipe, caroufredsel, touchstart

I would like to prevent touchstart from occurring when the user swipes through thumbnails,
at the moment when they swipe touchstart is also activated, is there a way to prevent this, here's my code:

```
$(document).on('touchstart click', '#thumbs a', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var timeout;
                        var clickedSlide = this.href.split('#').pop();
                        var moveToSlide = clickedSlide - 1;

                            $('#slider').trigger('slideTo', moveToSlide );
                        $(this).parent().addClass('hovered');
                            $(this).parent().siblings().not(this).removeClass('hovered');


                    });

                    $("#thumbs").swipe({
                          excludedElements: "button, input, select, textarea, .noSwipe",
                          swipeLeft: function() {
                            $('#thumbs').trigger('next', 5);
                          },
                          swipeRight: function() {
                            $('#thumbs').trigger('prev', 5);
                              }
```